# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).intlTelInput is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I am getting the below error in Google Chrome while at the 3rd step of an appointment process.

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).intlTelInput is not a function
  at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:330)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:3)
```

The line 330 at custom.js shows the below code:

```
var phone = jQuery("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber");
```

The full custom.js is available [here](http://hairreplacementclinic.com.au/wp-content/plugins/bookme/assets/js/custom.js)

The page where this error is generated is [here](http://hairreplacementclinic.com.au/appointments/) - It appears at Step 3. Details

When I disable the current theme and going to the default Twentyseventeen theme elimiates the error and the plugin works perfectly.

Please help me resolve the error in this current theme. What could be the problem.

I tried putting the jquery above every scripts but it didn't work either.

Here's the source code of the page where it works in the default Twentyseventeen theme  - https://pastebin.com/qKJZynLp

And here's the source code of the page where it do not work - https://pastebin.com/CNV8wfmK

Please help.

Comment: you include jquery after it so it overrides the plugin.

Comment: Could you please be specific in terms of which file and where should it be. Don't mind but trying to learn a few things.

Comment: You include the jquery library more than one time. look at the jquery references. You have it in the head and in the body

Comment: Yes, you are very correct. I have that jquery/jquery.min.js in the footer which overrides the plugin. I have now removed it and it is working perfectly fine. Thanks a ton mate.

Comment: try to include jquery before angular

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. I place the following code towards the top of the page so it loaded the libraries before it got to the intlTelInput section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="location/to/intl-tel-input/css/intlTelInput.css">
<script src="location/to/intl-tel-input/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
```

Then I initialised the code with the following

```
var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
window.intlTelInput(input);
```

I didn't use jQuery due to what they state on their git

> since v14 we have removed the jQuery dependency. See below for how to initialise and use the plugin with pure JavaScript. If you want to stick with the jQuery version, there is now a separate jQuery wrapped version.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Noe. Same error. tried exactly as specified. `index.php:40 Uncaught TypeError: window.intlTelInput is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this problem as well and the above answers didn't help so I thought I"d throw in my 2c answer.

The problem was in the references to intlTelInput. These ones worked:

```
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
```

I initialized the control with the following (it's worth noting this didn't default the way it's allegedly supposed to with the geo IP lookup, though).

```
const input = document.querySelector("#mobileNumber");
window.intlTelInput(input, {
    initialCounry: "auto",
    geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
            const countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "us";
            callback(countryCode);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Treid this exactly, does not work. `Uncaught TypeError: window.intlTelInput is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

app/code/Magecomp/Sms/view/frontend/web/countryflag/js/intlTelInput.min.js:
Replace "define" with "require".

```
define(["jquery"],function(b){...
```

to

```
require(["jquery"],function(b){...
```

Answer (score -2):

Do the following steps :

First check the following files are included in your code or not?

```
 1. <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/intlTelInput.css">
 2. <script src="/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
 3. <script src="/js/utils.js"></script>
```

If you have included above files properly than you never getting error like this : `Uncaught TypeError: jquery.intlTelInput is not a funciton`

Comment: nope, just tried it doesn't work `index.php:42 Uncaught TypeError: window.intlTelInput is not a function`. This `iti = $("#tel").intlTelInput(....` works but I cannot get the object back to retrieve the country codes. `iti.` just returns the form field I want to be able to do this `var countryData = iti.getSelectedCountryData();`