# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression [intlTelInput]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to use intl-tel-input in Asp.net core 6.0 razor pages
Here is my Scripts

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tbxPhone').intlTelInput();
    });
```

But gives an error

Errors in console;

```
intlTelInput.js:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-ZÃ€-Ã¿ ]$/: Range out of order in character class

jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://localhost:7283/SignUp:99:28)
at j (https://localhost:7283/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
at k (https://localhost:7283/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (SignUp:99:28)
at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).intlTelInput is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292582/uncaught-typeerror-jquery-intltelinput-is-not-a-function)

Comment: It looks like you have a 
extra space in `^[a-zA-ZÃ€-Ã¿ ]$`.And your `jquery 3.1.1` is not compatible with your `intlTelInput.js`.

Comment: Show your whole Html code along with js declarations.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens due to the charset of the script file to fix it you can use the below code when calling the script file.

```
<script src="intlTelInput.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```